# App goes into minute-long refresh loop after changes to code

Tags: angular-cli

I don't really know how to explain it, so here's a video of what's happening: https://www.loom.com/share/39e23f1e63c6483c82a308f8b457c273?sid=9cabf239-b99c-4dbf-9259-17bcb749ea52

Whenever I make a change to my code while serving the app, the browser goes into a reload frenzy for about a minute before finally displaying my application again. This started a couple of weeks ago, is happening to no one else on my team, but it is happening to me in two different folders (I have the project checked out twice).

It's super annoying because I have to wait for it each time before I can test my changes.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: "is happening to no one else on my team" could you disable your chrome plugins, other browsers if this issue happens and finally maybe npm cache clean and fresh npm install and npm run start

Comment: It appeared to be a browser issue. I noticed it didn't happen in another browser or even in another Chrome profile. Cleared browser data and the problem has disappeared. Thanks for the pointers!